# set a bit via a macro if it is defined with a value

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to move header information into C code without actually writing code.  Here's and example of a header that defines how many ADCs that are in a system:

```
//example definition
#define CONF_USEADC2 6  /*ADC2 on SPI2*/
#define CONF_USEADC3 7 /*ADC3 on SPI4*/
```

Depending on certain conditions, this hardware will be present or not, and for that reason, there's a byte with the data that tells you if there's the ADCs just so you know how many are in the system (there's a bus constraint so your data is slower if you have 2 ADCs on).  I have between 1 and 24 ADCs on a JDEC bus.  The code that creates the bits currently looks like the following:

```
#ifdef CONF_USEADC2
uc_tmp = uc_tmp | (1 << CONF_USEADC2);
#endif
#ifdef CONF_USEADC3
uc_tmp = uc_tmp | (1 << CONF_USEADC3);
#endif
```

Which bit is set is based on the value of definition, and one can see how this quickly could become a mess.  There are many of these definitions in reality which is making things a total mess. 
Is there some smart way with MACROs to create method where one could just pass something like `CONF_USEADC2` to a macro and if it's defined it sets the bit and if it is not, it just ignores it?   In this way, I could have `macro(CONF_USEADC2)` which would replace that code above to help with readability.

Comment: Shouldn't you have only one definition, not two?  Also, you can use `#if defined ()`, `#elif defined()`, etc.

Comment: @FiddlingBits You basically uncomment/comment lines in a header to change the DMA and some other hardware items.  There's just so much configuration based on the CPU and ADC that the code is prone to errors on that #ifdef section.

Comment: I think you need a different approach. Don't edit library headers to suit the application. Make another definition in your program, either `#define MYCONFADC CONF_USEADC2` or `#define MYCONFADC CONF_USEADC3`. Then you simply do `uc_tmp = uc_tmp | (1 << MYCONFADC);` and no conditional compilation is needed, and no chance of setting `uc_tmp` twice.

Comment: @WeatherVane The issue is that when you have multiple ADCs, things fall apart.  '''uc_tmp = uc_tmp | (1 << MYCONFADC)'''   I will update the question to be more clear

Comment: So you are saying the number of ADCs is a runtime configuration? Then build a `struct` (for tidiness) with values initialised by the number of ADCs configured on the system. Have a different `init` function for each type of setup, and for this particular item a `struct` member say `int conf_useadcbit` which will be set to `CONF_USEADC2` or to `CONF_USEADC3`. You then might have `uc_tmp |= 1 << config.conf_useadcbit;`

Comment: @WeatherVane Depending on the system, depends on what you compile in.  This is because of the hardware dependencies.  I like what you propose; however, due to the fact that "deep in the guts" are DMA and other hardware relating things, there's #ifdef for the different DMA settings as well.  I wanted to trickle down my bit problem to cover more things as well.  This is the issue with legacy code, you sometimes cannot easily undo the past. :/